# How to use a .pgm image file as a custom map in Mapsui

Tags: c#, wpf, ros, mapsui

I am developing a wpf app for controlling a ROS based robot. And I want to show a map from the robot in the UI using Mapsui. Currently I am using canvas to display the map so when I have a lot of waypoints and other indicators on the map, it's messy. And the manipulation and touch support is terrible.

I have came across [this.](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/issues/1000) But it involve tile structuring which is not okay for my project as I will just be getting a only.pgm file from the robot.

Is there a way I can just display the .pgm file as the background like I do in the canvas and then use layers and other good features of Mapsui on top?

Answer (score 3):

The current version (Mapsui 3.0.0) has no support for .pgm. You could build your own IProvider for that. This could be based on the [SharpMap code to load a .pgm](https://github.com/SharpMap/_SharpMap/blob/master/Branches/1.0/SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeoPackage/GeoPackage.cs).